# Why does this code demands so much memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am currently trying to solve a problem on one of the online programming contests. The limit for the program is 64 megabyte in this contest.

I wrote a program in Java that has a section of fields in the class declararation that works like this:

```
private int[] sizes = new int[1024]; // 4096 bytes
private boolean[][] compat = new boolean[1024][1024]; // 128 kb
private boolean[][] compat2 = new boolean[1024][1024]; // 128 kb

private long[][][] dp = new long[29000][51][2]; // About 3*8 = 24 megabytes
private int [][] masks  = new int[29000][2]; // About 240 kb
private int avail = 0; 
private int avail2 = 0;
private int[] positions = new int[500000]; // About 2 megabytes
private int[][] ranges = new int[29000][2]; // About 240 kb
private int[][] maskToPos = new int[1024][1024]; // About 4 megabytes
private int[][][] init = new int[29000][51][2]; // About 3*4 = 12 megabytes
```

Now, the class has only a main procedure and some cycles inside it, without any additional arrays declared (just some variable to iterate through the cycles). However, then I tried to run this code on my local machine with the key -Xmx64m, I've got an OutOfMemoryError. It only managed to execute with the key -Xmx128m.

I also tried to lauch in on the online server, it gave the same error, and also gave additional info that my program used about 148460 kb.

But why so much? As far as I can calculate from the fragment above, it only should use about 40 megabytes. Is there something wrong with this calculation in the comments?

Comment: Don't forget that the JVM also needs memory for itself.

Comment: And why does it need so much memory in order to store all these variables?

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say this looks like WAY overkill for any online judging site (mostly because i've solved about 300-500 problems per a lot of sites and never had to write something like this) also Java has overhead for storing metadata that you're not taking into account. Rethink your solution is probably your best bet as you should never need that much memory.

Comment: I will rethink my solution if necessary. So, what exactly is stored in metadata that it causes such an overhead?

Comment: `new boolean[1024][1024]` is 1 MB, not 128 KB.

Comment: @SPIRiT_1984 Well, class file definitions and the string literal store for starters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These two are the biggest killers:

```
private long[][][] dp = new long[29000][51][2]; // About 3*8 = 24 megabytes
private int[][][] init = new int[29000][51][2]; // About 3*4 = 12 megabytes
```

Looking at the second, for example... that isn't 12 megabytes. You've got 29000 `int[][]` objects, **each of which** contains references to 51 `int[]` objects, each of which contains 2 integers.

Assuming a 32-bit reference size and 16 bytes of overhead for the array itself (length + common object overhead) that means the `int[][]` objects are each of size 51 * 4 + 16 = 220 bytes, and then the `int[]` objects are each of size 24 bytes. But you've got 29000 * 51 of those 24-byte objects - which is 35MB just in itself... Then there's the 29000 `int[][]` objects, which is another 6MB... (Then there's the top level array itself, but that's only about 120K.)

Basically, you need to remember that Java doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays: it has arrays of arrays, and each array is an object, with separate overhead. I suggest you may want to use:

```
private int[] init = new int[29000 * 51 * 2];
```

instead, and work out appropriate offsets yourself. (Ditto for dp, which is even worse as it's `long` values rather than `int` values, making each of the 29000 * 51 arrays take at least 32 bytes rather than 24.)

Even just reversing the order in which you treat the dimensions would *help*:

```
private long[][][] dp = new long[2][51][29000];
private int[][][] init = new int[2][51][29000];
```

Now for each of these variables, there's one top-level array-of-arrays-of-arrays, 2 arrays-of-arrays, and 102 arrays of `long` or `int`. That corresponds to a *lot* less overhead.

Your other calculations are incorrect too, but I think these two arrays-of-arrays-of-arrays are the worst.

Comment: I guess my dark C++ past played a bad trick on me, I used to that int[29000][51][2] is as much memory as int[29000*51*2]. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Which is also a good reason to consider using `int[29000][51*2]` or `int[29000*51*2]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that multidimensional arrays in Java are not real multi-dimensional arrays; if they were, then Java would support the [x,y] notation. But it doesn't. Because multi-dimensional arrays in Java are implemented as arrays of arrays. So, `new boolean[1024][1024]` is in fact 1024 array objects, each one of them containing 1024 booleans. (1KB each.)

I do not remember which dimension is major and which is minor, but judging by the fact that your program runs out of memory, the first dimension is probably the major one. So, `new long[29000][51][2]` is 29000*51=1479000 array objects, each one of them containing 2 long values. So, with so many objects, and considering the overhead per object, forget about it!

Comment: I thought that boolean is 1-bit, not 1-byte?

Comment: Few (if any) JVM implementations optimize the memory use of boolean. They prefer the simplicity of addressing a boolean by a byte address like all other primitives, and leave memory compression to objects like BitSet.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly noted above, `long[29000][51][2]` takes more than 24 megabytes. You can try reducing the amount of memory by moving the largest dimension to the end of the array, like this:

```
private long[][][] dp = new long[51][2][29000];
```

This may be enough for your program to squeak by in the programming contest.

Answer (score 1):

One minor suggestion:  I'd try making all your declarations "final".  Big arrays cause problems with memory allocation because not only must the space be found, *contiguous* space must be found.  Java can move things around to make space, but if it takes too long to do so it will throw an out-of-memory exception even when the space is theoretically available.  You seem to be dodging this problem by grabbing all your memory up front and keeping it till the program finishes.  Using "final" would let the JVM know you're serious about this and perhaps let it allocate space in a manner that helps you out.

This may not help the JVM.  I've found Java getting awfully clever these last few years, and it may not need you to tell it what is final and what is not.  People *do* need to be told, however.  Using "final" will keep you and whoever else changes the code from accidentally reallocating space, say with a statement like `positions = new int[500010];` elsewhere in your code and overwhelming the JVM/garbage collector.